# When (and when not) to run the `sanitize` method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, ruby-on-rails-5, sanitization

I would like to definitively know when to run (and when not e.g. because it's automatically run) the [`sanitize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize) method throughout my Rails 5 application.

For example, in my view files, embedded inside `<%= ... %>`, should I use these?

```
sanitize(record.value)

link_to(sanitize(record.value), ...)

tag.span(sanitize(record.value))

t("translation_string_html", :argument_value => sanitize(record.value))
```

or these?

```
record.value

link_to(record.value, ...)

tag.span(record.value)

t("translation_string_html", :argument_value => record.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sanitizing is not necessary when using the Rails helpers generally.

For example if you follow the `link_to` method to its end here is the relevant line

https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/ActionView%2FHelpers%2FTagHelper%2FTagBuilder:content_tag_string

```
def content_tag_string(name, content, options, escape = true)
  tag_options = tag_options(options, escape) if options
  content     = ERB::Util.unwrapped_html_escape(content) if escape
  "<#{name}#{tag_options}>#{PRE_CONTENT_STRINGS[name]}#{content}</#{name}>".html_safe
end
```

As you can see it is both html escaped with some utils from Erb and then also with `html_safe` before finally returning.